# Javascript password validation

Tags: javascript, validation, passwords

Can anyone suggest an easy password validation using javascript. I need it to be at least 4 characters long and contain min 1 letter and 1 number.

This is a school project so its really only a simple validation needed to make sure they are entering in the required characters.

I am using

```
<textarea id="special_info" name="address" onfocus="this.value=''" rows="5" cols="40" >Please enter your address...
            </textarea>
            <div id="maxcar">(Maximum characters: 200)
            </div>
```

My javascript is in this format

```
function validate_form(){

valid=true;

var letters=/^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
var numbers=/^[0-9]+$/;
var email=document.order_form.user_email.value;
var invalid = [];

if (document.order_form.first_name.value.search(letters)==-1){
invalid.push("*First Name")
}   

if (document.order_form.surname.value.search(letters)==-1){
invalid.push("*Surname Name")
}

if (email.indexOf("@")<1 || email.lastIndexOf(".")<email.indexOf("@")+2 
|| email.lastIndexOf(".")+2>=email.length){
invalid.push("*Email")
}

if (invalid.length != 0)
{alert("Please provide response: \n" + invalid.join("\n") ); 
    valid = false;
    invalid = [];}


return valid;}
```

Comment: What's the question? What problem are your facing? Where do you have troubles?

Comment: lol Well I am really not sure how to write it using the same format used above. I know its meant to be kind of simple however I am very confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// returns true if the form was valid; false otherwise.

function validateForm() {

    var allLetters = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    var letter = /[a-zA-Z]/;
    var number = /[0-9]/;

    var firstName = document.order_form.first_name.value;
    var surname = document.order_form.surname.value;
    var email = document.order_form.user_email.value;
    var password = document.order_form.password.value;

    var invalid = [];

    if (!allLetters.test(firstName)) {
        invalid.push("*First Name");
    }

    if (!allLetters.test(surname)) {
        invalid.push("*Surname Name");
    }

    if (email.indexOf("@") < 1 || email.lastIndexOf(".") < email.indexOf("@") + 2 || email.lastIndexOf(".") + 2 >= email.length) {
        invalid.push("*Email");
    }

    if (password.length < 4 || !letter.test(password) || !number.test(password)) {
        invalid.push("*Password");
    }

    if (invalid.length != 0) {
        alert("Please provide response: \n" + invalid.join("\n"));
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Give it a good read, run it, and ask questions if something is unclear.

Notice the use of [RegExp.test](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp) instead of String.search.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regular expression and check the length. The regular expression is a case insensitive check for one letter and one number in any order. The length must be greater than 3.

```
function testString(s) {
  var re = /[a-z]\d|\d[a-z]/i;
  return re.test(s) && s.length > 3;
}
```